# Renewcommand \[\] to include \par afterwards

Tags: equations, environments, tex4ebook

I'd like to redefine the \[ \] command to have a \par afterwards, or rename it to be equation*

The reason is that \[\] on its own for some reason causes formatting issues when converting to epub (using tex4ebook), which you can see in the pictures below. The picture is obtained from the code

```
\[ abc \]\par
Here is some text with an inline equation ($a$), and some more text.
```

With the \par either present (looks good) or commented out (looks bad).
[image: With \par]
[image: Without \par]

I tried several methods, two of which are below, with and without amsmath, and nothing worked.

```
\def\[#1\]{\[#1\]\par}
```

```
\renewcommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\renewcommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

btw, the pdf looks fine in both cases, so the issue arises in the conversion to epub. I realize that adding \par is a bandaid rather than fixing the issue, but it works so it's fine with me.

**EDIT**:
The MWE shows that it's due to the "most" option in tcolorbox. I'm not nearly enough of an expert to know why, but when that package is included with that option, the formatting looks bad, and when that package is excluded (or included without "most"), formatting is good (only following \[\]).

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
% \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\[ abc \]%\par
Here is some text with an inline equation ($a$), and some more text.
\end{document}
```

After this, I run `perl latexmkrcEbook` using the latexmkrc downloaded from overleaf via [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/testing-tex4ebook-to-generate-basic-epubs/fdthzgghvbcd).

**EDIT**: Solved with an update, see comments. Many thanks to @michal.h21 and @DavidCarlisle!

Comment: `\let\oldzzz\] \renewcommand\]{\oldzzz\par}`  but how will you mark up the usual case where the following text doesn't start a paragraph/shouldn't be indented?

Comment: did you intend to add `\par` in the second definition (with `equation*`) ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The oldzzz suggestion doesn't work. I don't get the formatting issue when I use \begin{equation}abc\end{equation}. Or align. It's only with \\[\\]. Problem is that there are too many \\[\\] over too many files to manually change them all.

Comment: But this also doesn't work: ```\renewcommand\]{\oldzzz\par hello}```, as in doesn't print out ```hello```.

Comment: any reasonable editor would change all the `\[` to `\begin{equation}` in one go, so it shouldn't matter how many there are?

Comment: is your TeX distribution up to date? I get correct paragraph with up-to date TeX Live.

Comment: it is true that I fixed definition of `\[` and `\]` few weeks ago, so it is possible that you could get this issue with older TeX4ht versions.

Comment: @michal.h21 Yes, just installed a few weeks ago, running texlive2020 with files downloaded off overleaf (project was too big to compile online). The present issue is from converting to ebook. tex4ebook is v0.3c.

Comment: it would help if you provided a complete small one equation document that people could test

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. See my edit.

Comment: as @michal.h21 is here I won't try to guess what tex4ht is or isn't doing:-)

Comment: @michal.h21 Apologies for my rapid-fire edits. It seems to be caused by the 'most' input to tcolorbox. Leaving that out fixes the MWE, but unfortunately screws up many other things in the real doc.

Comment: I get correct result on my system, using command `tex4ebook -f epub3 sample.tex`. Even if I use the `tcolorbox` package. Maybe try to run `tlmgr update --all` to update your TeX Live installation. I've fixed some issues with `tcolorbox` recently.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, now it's working. Thanks a lot for your super-fast help. It's much appreciated. btw, I don't think I can accept a comment. I'll edit the original post.

Comment: that's good to hear that it works now :)